# Review validation failed: userId: Path `userId` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

When I make API request in thunder client a message says  Review validation failed: userId: Path `userId` is required.

*********    IMPORTANT NOTE      *****
I create api request in thunder client by folllowing syntax

```
  "noteId":"63ff4386680d63958c49306c",
  "star":3,
  "desc":"Good Note Like it"

}
```

and i don't give userId bexause in controller i have writted following syntax

```
  const newReview = new Review({
    userId: req.userId,  //  ********  Important   *******
    noteId: req.body.noteId,
    desc: req.body.desc,
    star: req.body.star,
  });
```

This is review schema and model

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const ReviewSchema = new Schema(
  {
    noteId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    star: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      enum:[1,2,3,4,5]
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export default mongoose.model("Review", ReviewSchema);
```

This is a review controller for creating request

```
import Review from "../models/review.js";
import Note from "../models/Note.js";
import { createError } from "../error.js";

export const createReview = async (req, res, next) => {
  const newReview = new Review({
    userId: req.userId,
    noteId: req.body.noteId,
    desc: req.body.desc,
    star: req.body.star,
  });

  try {
    const review = await Review.findOne({
      noteId: req.body.noteId,
      userId: req.userId,
    });

    if (review)
      return next(
        createError(403, "You have already created a review for this note!")
      );

    const savedReview = await newReview.save();

    await Note.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.noteId, {
      $inc: { totalStars: req.body.star, starNumber: 1 },
    });
    res.status(201).send(savedReview);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

This is a review router for creating request  for  creating review

```
import express from "express";
import { verifyToken } from "../verifyToken.js";
import {
  createReview,
  getReviews,
  deleteReview,
} from "../controllers/reviews.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", verifyToken,createReview )
```

This is verify token middlewear  for verifying logged in user

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { createError } from "./error.js";

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  if (!token) return next(createError(401, "You are not authenticated!"));

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return next(createError(403, "Token is not valid!"));
    req.user = user;
    next()
  });
};
```

This is index.js

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
import NotesRoutes from "./routes/notes.js";
import reviewRoutes from "./routes/reviews.js";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";
import conversationRoutes from "./routes/conversations.js";
import messagesRoutes from "./routes/messages.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
 

const app = express();
dotenv.config();


// Connection to database MongoDB
const connect = () => {
  mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to Database");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err;
  });
};

// host and Port name
const port = 80;
const hostname = "127.0.0.1";

//middlewares
app.use(cors())
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());

//Api routes

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/notes", NotesRoutes);
app.use("/api/reviews", reviewRoutes);
app.use("/api/conversations", conversationRoutes);
app.use("/api/messeges", messagesRoutes);

//error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const status = err.status || 500;
  const message = err.message || "Something went wrong!";
  return res.status(status).json({
    success: false,
    status,
    message,
  });
});

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  connect()
  console.log(`App is running at port http://${hostname}:${port} `);
});
```

Comment: You are using `req.userId` but in jwt you assign user to `req.user` so shouldn't it be more like `req.user.Id` or `req.user.userId` ?? Try `console.log(req.UserId, req.user)` in createReview function to see what exists and what does not.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time    it was     `userId: req.user.id `